# General patterns for partial sums of generalized A341392, A284005 and A329369

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, generating-functions, recurrences

Let
$$\ell(n)=\left\lfloor\log_2 n\right\rfloor$$
$$f(n)=n-2^{\ell(n)}$$
$$\operatorname{wt}(2n+1)=\operatorname{wt}(n)+1, \operatorname{wt}(2n)=\operatorname{wt}(n), \operatorname{wt}(0)=0$$
$$T(n,k)=\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2^k}\right\rfloor\operatorname{mod}2$$
Here $f(n)$ is the same as $n$ without the most significant bit, $\operatorname{wt}(n)$ is the binary weight of $n$ or the number of $1$'s in the binary expansion of $n$ and $T(n,k)$ is the $(k+1)$-th bit from the right side in the binary representation of $n$.

Let
$$b(n,m,k;g(p))=m\cdot g(n)\cdot b(f(n),m,k;g(p))+k\sum\limits_{j=0}^{\ell(n)}(1-T(n,j))b(f(n)+2^j(1-T(n,j)),m,k;g(p))$$
Here $g(p)$ is arbitrary function. Also

- $b(n,1,1;1)$ is [A341392](https://oeis.org/A341392)
- $b(n,1,1;\operatorname{wt}(p)+1)$ is [A284005](https://oeis.org/A284005)
- $b(n,1,1;\ell(p)-\operatorname{wt}(p)+2)$ is [A329369](https://oeis.org/A329369)

Let
$$s(n,m,k;g(p))=\sum\limits_{j=0}^{2^n-1}b(j,m,k;g(p))$$

Let
$$t(p,q)=\ell(p)-(2-q)(\operatorname{wt}(p)-1)+1$$

Known (conjectured) general patterns for $m,k\in\mathbb{R}$:
$$s(n,m,k;1)=R_1(n,0)$$
where
$$R_1(n,q)=R_1(n-1,q+1)+m\sum\limits_{j=0}^{q}\binom{q}{j}k^{q-j}R_1(n-1,j), R_1(0,q)=1$$

---

E.g.f. for $s(n,m,k;1)$ satisfies
$$\operatorname{exp}\left(x + m\frac{\operatorname{exp}(kx) - 1}{k}\right)$$
This is the only proven result. It was proved by Peter Taylor [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/446656/231922).

---

E.g.f for $s(n,m,k;t(p,0))$ with $1$ prepended satisfies
$$A_1(x)=\operatorname{exp}\left(x + m\int\int (A_1(x))^k \, dx \, dx\right)$$

---

$$s(n,m,k;t(p,1))=R_2(n,0)$$
where
$$R_2(n,q)=R_2(n-1,q+1)+m\sum\limits_{j=0}^{q}\binom{q+1}{j}k^{q-j}R_2(n-1,j), R_2(0,q)=1$$

---

$$s(n,m,k;t(p,1))=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n+1} {n+1 \brace i}(m-k)^{n-i+1}\prod\limits_{j=0}^{i-1}(kj+1)$$

---

G.f. for $s(n,m,k;t(p,1))$ with $1$ prepended is $\frac{1}{G_1(0)}$ where
$$G_1(j)=1-\frac{x(kj+1)}{1-\frac{mx(j+1)}{G_1(j+1)}}$$

---

G.f. for $s(n,m,k;t(p,3))$ is $\frac{1}{G_2(0)}$ where
$$G_2(j)=1-x(kj+1)-\frac{mx(j+1)}{G_2(j+1)}$$

---

E.g.f. for $s(n,m,k;t(p,k))$ satisfies
$$A_2(x)=(1 + \int A_2(x) \, dx)(1 + m\int (A_2(x))^k \, dx)$$

---

I would like to have a collection of general patterns at least for $s(n,m,k;t(p,q))$ (where $m,k\in\mathbb{R}$) to guess (if possible) the general case. I think that it is possible to place several patterns at once in one answer. I will definitely attach all new patterns to the question. I am also interested in the proofs of these patterns (but of course I need the patterns themselves more).

Also, please write in the comments how you can call $b(n,m,k;g(p))$ as well as its summation through $s(n,m,k;g(p))$.